# JSON Formatting for Robot Framework Data Driven Scenario

Tags: json, robotframework

I have found many tutorials on JSON formatting, but cannot find the issue with my JSON.
Can someone take a look and tell me where it is broken?

The goal is to have 3 different scenarios where a user picks answers to a test based on one of the 3 acuity divisions.

Each acuity section has 4 subsections, and each subsection has its own answers.

```
{"acuity1":
    {"sec1":
        {       
        "ans1": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans2":{"\ue01b"},
         "ans3": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans4": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans5": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans6": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans7": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans8": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans9": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans10": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans11": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans12": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans13": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans14": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans15": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans16": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans17": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans18": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans19": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans20": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans21": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans22": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans23": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans24": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans25": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans26": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans27": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans28": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans29": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans30": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans31": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans32": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans33": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans34": {"\ue01f"},
         "ans35": {"\ue01f"}
        }
    },
     {"sec2":
         {
            "ans1":1 {"\ue01b"},
            "ans2": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans3": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans4": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans5": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans6": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans7": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans8": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans9": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans10": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans11": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans12": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans13": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans14": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans15": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans16": {"\ue01f"}
         }
    },
     {"sec3":
         {
            "ans1": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans2": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans3": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans4": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans5": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans6": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans7": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans8": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans9": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans10": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans11": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans12": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans13": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans14": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans15": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans16": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans17": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans18": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans19": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans20": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans21": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans22": {"\ue01b"}
         }
    },
     {"sec4":
         {
            "ans1": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans2": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans3": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans4": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans5": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans6": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans7": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans8": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans9": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans10": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans11": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans12": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans13": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans14": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans15": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans16": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans17": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans18": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans19": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans20": {"\ue01b"}
         }
    }  
}
{"acuity2":
    {"sec1":
        {       
        "ans1": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans2":{"\ue01d"},
         "ans3": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans4": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans5": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans6": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans7": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans8": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans9": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans10": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans11": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans12": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans13": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans14": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans15": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans16": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans17": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans18": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans19": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans20": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans21": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans22": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans23": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans24": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans25": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans26": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans27": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans28": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans29": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans30": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans31": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans32": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans33": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans34": {"\ue01d"},
         "ans35": {"\ue01d"}
        },
     {"sec2":
         {
            "ans1":1 {"\ue01d"},
            "ans2": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans3": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans4": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans5": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans6": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans7": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans8": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans9": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans10": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans11": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans12": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans13": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans14": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans15": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans16": {"\ue01d"}
         }
    },
     {"sec3":
         {
            "ans1": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans2": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans3": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans4": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans5": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans6": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans7": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans8": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans9": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans10": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans11": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans12": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans13": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans14": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans15": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans16": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans17": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans18": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans19": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans20": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans21": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans22": {"\ue01d"}
         }
    },
     {"sec4":
         {
            "ans1": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans2": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans3": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans4": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans5": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans6": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans7": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans8": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans9": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans10": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans11": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans12": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans13": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans14": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans15": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans16": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans17": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans18": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans19": {"\ue01d"},
            "ans20": {"\ue01d"}
         }
    } 
},
{"acuity3":
    {"sec1":
           {       
           "ans1": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans2":{"\ue01f"},
            "ans3": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans4": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans5": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans6": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans7": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans8": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans9": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans10": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans11": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans12": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans13": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans14": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans15": {"\ue01f"},
            "ans16": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans17": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans18": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans19": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans20": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans21": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans22": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans23": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans24": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans25": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans26": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans27": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans28": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans29": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans30": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans31": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans32": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans33": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans34": {"\ue01b"},
            "ans35": {"\ue01b"}
           },
    },
        {"sec2":
            {
               "ans1":1 {"\ue01f"},
               "ans2": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans3": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans4": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans5": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans6": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans7": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans8": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans9": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans10": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans11": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans12": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans13": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans14": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans15": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans16": {"\ue01b"}
            },
        },
        {"sec3":
            {
               "ans1": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans2": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans3": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans4": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans5": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans6": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans7": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans8": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans9": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans10": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans11": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans12": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans13": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans14": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans15": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans16": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans17": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans18": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans19": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans20": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans21": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans22": {"\ue01f"}
            }, 
        },       
        {"sec4":
            {
               "ans1": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans2": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans3": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans4": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans5": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans6": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans7": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans8": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans9": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans10": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans11": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans12": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans13": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans14": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans15": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans16": {"\ue01b"},
               "ans17": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans18": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans19": {"\ue01f"},
               "ans20": {"\ue01f"}
            }
       }   
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the curly braces from the dictionaries without keys. The encoded values, are inside dictionaries. They should be values for the `ans` keys.

Also, you have an error at ans1 (repeated in another dictionary), 1 after column:

```
{"sec2":
         {
            "ans1":1 {"\ue01d"},
(...)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had noticed the error at ans1 and corrected it after posting.  Can you clarify about removing the curly braces from the dictionaries without keys?  Is this what you were thinking:  "acuity1":
    "sec1":
        {       
        "ans1": {"\ue01b"},
         "ans2":{"\ue01b"},

Comment: So, you fixed like I proposed. Please accept my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out i needed to add some endings and rearrange it a bit.
Final solution:

```
    {"acuity1":[
    {"sec1":[{       
            "ans1": "\ue01b",
            "ans2":"\ue01b",
            "ans3": "\ue01b",
            "ans4": "\ue01b",
            "ans5": "\ue01b",
            "ans6": "\ue01b",
            "ans7": "\ue01b",
            "ans8": "\ue01b",
            "ans9": "\ue01b",
            "ans10": "\ue01b",
            "ans11": "\ue01b",
            "ans12": "\ue01b",
            "ans13": "\ue01b",
            "ans14": "\ue01b",
            "ans15": "\ue01b",
            "ans16": "\ue01f",
            "ans17": "\ue01f",
            "ans18": "\ue01f",
            "ans19": "\ue01f",
            "ans20": "\ue01f",
            "ans21": "\ue01f",
            "ans22": "\ue01f",
            "ans23": "\ue01f",
            "ans24": "\ue01f",
            "ans25": "\ue01f",
            "ans26": "\ue01f",
            "ans27": "\ue01f",
            "ans28": "\ue01f",
            "ans29": "\ue01f",
            "ans30": "\ue01f",
            "ans31": "\ue01f",
            "ans32": "\ue01f",
            "ans33": "\ue01f",
            "ans34": "\ue01f",
            "ans35": "\ue01f"
        }]},
     {"sec2":[{
            "ans1": "\ue01b",
            "ans2": "\ue01b",
            "ans3": "\ue01b",
            "ans4": "\ue01b",
            "ans5": "\ue01b",
            "ans6": "\ue01b",
            "ans7": "\ue01b",
            "ans8": "\ue01b",
            "ans9": "\ue01f",
            "ans10": "\ue01f",
            "ans11": "\ue01f",
            "ans12": "\ue01f",
            "ans13": "\ue01f",
            "ans14": "\ue01f",
            "ans15": "\ue01f",
            "ans16": "\ue01f"
         }]},
     {"sec3":[{
            "ans1": "\ue01b",
            "ans2": "\ue01b",
            "ans3": "\ue01b",
            "ans4": "\ue01b",
            "ans5": "\ue01b",
            "ans6": "\ue01b",
            "ans7": "\ue01b",
            "ans8": "\ue01b",
            "ans9": "\ue01b",
            "ans10": "\ue01b",
            "ans11": "\ue01f",
            "ans12": "\ue01f",
            "ans13": "\ue01f",
            "ans14": "\ue01f",
            "ans15": "\ue01f",
            "ans16": "\ue01f",
            "ans17": "\ue01f",
            "ans18": "\ue01f",
            "ans19": "\ue01b",
            "ans20": "\ue01b",
            "ans21": "\ue01b",
            "ans22": "\ue01b"
         }]},
     {"sec4":[{
            "ans1": "\ue01b",
            "ans2": "\ue01b",
            "ans3": "\ue01b",
            "ans4": "\ue01b",
            "ans5": "\ue01b",
            "ans6": "\ue01b",
            "ans7": "\ue01b",
            "ans8": "\ue01b",
            "ans9": "\ue01f",
            "ans10": "\ue01f",
            "ans11": "\ue01f",
            "ans12": "\ue01f",
            "ans13": "\ue01f",
            "ans14": "\ue01f",
            "ans15": "\ue01f",
            "ans16": "\ue01f",
            "ans17": "\ue01b",
            "ans18": "\ue01b",
            "ans19": "\ue01b",
            "ans20": "\ue01b"
         }]} , 
{"acuity2":[
    {"sec1":[{       
            "ans1": "\ue01d",
            "ans2":"\ue01d",
            "ans3": "\ue01d",
            "ans4": "\ue01d",
            "ans5": "\ue01d",
            "ans6": "\ue01d",
            "ans7": "\ue01d",
            "ans8": "\ue01d",
            "ans9": "\ue01d",
            "ans10": "\ue01d",
            "ans11": "\ue01d",
            "ans12": "\ue01d",
            "ans13": "\ue01d",
            "ans14": "\ue01d",
            "ans15": "\ue01d",
            "ans16": "\ue01d",
            "ans17": "\ue01d",
            "ans18": "\ue01d",
            "ans19": "\ue01d",
            "ans20": "\ue01d",
            "ans21": "\ue01d",
            "ans22": "\ue01d",
            "ans23": "\ue01d",
            "ans24": "\ue01d",
            "ans25": "\ue01d",
            "ans26": "\ue01d",
            "ans27": "\ue01d",
            "ans28": "\ue01d",
            "ans29": "\ue01d",
            "ans30": "\ue01d",
            "ans31": "\ue01d",
            "ans32": "\ue01d",
            "ans33": "\ue01d",
            "ans34": "\ue01d",
            "ans35": "\ue01d"
        }]},
     {"sec2":[{
            "ans1": "\ue01d",
            "ans2": "\ue01d",
            "ans3": "\ue01d",
            "ans4": "\ue01d",
            "ans5": "\ue01d",
            "ans6": "\ue01d",
            "ans7": "\ue01d",
            "ans8": "\ue01d",
            "ans9": "\ue01d",
            "ans10": "\ue01d",
            "ans11": "\ue01d",
            "ans12": "\ue01d",
            "ans13": "\ue01d",
            "ans14": "\ue01d",
            "ans15": "\ue01d",
            "ans16": "\ue01d"
         }]},
     {"sec3":[{
            "ans1": "\ue01d",
            "ans2": "\ue01d",
            "ans3": "\ue01d",
            "ans4": "\ue01d",
            "ans5": "\ue01d",
            "ans6": "\ue01d",
            "ans7": "\ue01d",
            "ans8": "\ue01d",
            "ans9": "\ue01d",
            "ans10": "\ue01d",
            "ans11": "\ue01d",
            "ans12": "\ue01d",
            "ans13": "\ue01d",
            "ans14": "\ue01d",
            "ans15": "\ue01d",
            "ans16": "\ue01d",
            "ans17": "\ue01d",
            "ans18": "\ue01d",
            "ans19": "\ue01d",
            "ans20": "\ue01d",
            "ans21": "\ue01d",
            "ans22": "\ue01d"
         }]},
     {"sec4":[{
            "ans1": "\ue01d",
            "ans2": "\ue01d",
            "ans3": "\ue01d",
            "ans4": "\ue01d",
            "ans5": "\ue01d",
            "ans6": "\ue01d",
            "ans7": "\ue01d",
            "ans8": "\ue01d",
            "ans9": "\ue01d",
            "ans10": "\ue01d",
            "ans11": "\ue01d",
            "ans12": "\ue01d",
            "ans13": "\ue01d",
            "ans14": "\ue01d",
            "ans15": "\ue01d",
            "ans16": "\ue01d",
            "ans17": "\ue01d",
            "ans18": "\ue01d",
            "ans19": "\ue01d",
            "ans20": "\ue01d"
         }]},
{"acuity3":[
    {"sec1":[{       
            "ans1": "\ue01f",
            "ans2":"\ue01f",
            "ans3": "\ue01f",
            "ans4": "\ue01f",
            "ans5": "\ue01f",
            "ans6": "\ue01f",
            "ans7": "\ue01f",
            "ans8": "\ue01f",
            "ans9": "\ue01f",
            "ans10": "\ue01f",
            "ans11": "\ue01f",
            "ans12": "\ue01f",
            "ans13": "\ue01f",
            "ans14": "\ue01f",
            "ans15": "\ue01f",
            "ans16": "\ue01b",
            "ans17": "\ue01b",
            "ans18": "\ue01b",
            "ans19": "\ue01b",
            "ans20": "\ue01b",
            "ans21": "\ue01b",
            "ans22": "\ue01b",
            "ans23": "\ue01b",
            "ans24": "\ue01b",
            "ans25": "\ue01b",
            "ans26": "\ue01b",
            "ans27": "\ue01b",
            "ans28": "\ue01b",
            "ans29": "\ue01b",
            "ans30": "\ue01b",
            "ans31": "\ue01b",
            "ans32": "\ue01b",
            "ans33": "\ue01b",
            "ans34": "\ue01b",
            "ans35": "\ue01b"
           }]},
        {"sec2":[{
            "ans1": "\ue01f",
            "ans2": "\ue01f",
            "ans3": "\ue01f",
            "ans4": "\ue01f",
            "ans5": "\ue01f",
            "ans6": "\ue01f",
            "ans7": "\ue01f",
            "ans8": "\ue01f",
            "ans9": "\ue01b",
            "ans10": "\ue01b",
            "ans11": "\ue01b",
            "ans12": "\ue01b",
            "ans13": "\ue01b",
            "ans14": "\ue01b",
            "ans15": "\ue01b",
            "ans16": "\ue01b"
            }]},
        {"sec3":[{
            "ans1": "\ue01f",
            "ans2": "\ue01f",
            "ans3": "\ue01f",
            "ans4": "\ue01f",
            "ans5": "\ue01f",
            "ans6": "\ue01f",
            "ans7": "\ue01f",
            "ans8": "\ue01f",
            "ans9": "\ue01f",
            "ans10": "\ue01f",
            "ans11": "\ue01b",
            "ans12": "\ue01b",
            "ans13": "\ue01b",
            "ans14": "\ue01b",
            "ans15": "\ue01b",
            "ans16": "\ue01b",
            "ans17": "\ue01b",
            "ans18": "\ue01b",
            "ans19": "\ue01f",
            "ans20": "\ue01f",
            "ans21": "\ue01f",
            "ans22": "\ue01f"
            }]},       
        {"sec4":[{
            "ans1": "\ue01f",
            "ans2": "\ue01f",
            "ans3": "\ue01f",
            "ans4": "\ue01f",
            "ans5": "\ue01f",
            "ans6": "\ue01f",
            "ans7": "\ue01f",
            "ans8": "\ue01f",
            "ans9": "\ue01b",
            "ans10": "\ue01b",
            "ans11": "\ue01b",
            "ans12": "\ue01b",
            "ans13": "\ue01b",
            "ans14": "\ue01b",
            "ans15": "\ue01b",
            "ans16": "\ue01b",
            "ans17": "\ue01f",
            "ans18": "\ue01f",
            "ans19": "\ue01f",
            "ans20": "\ue01f"
            }]}]
}]}]}
```